# Is the limit in $pv\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ taken in the $L^2$ sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I'm learning the distribution theory about the principal value and the question arises as I read about the statement that says
$H(f)=\frac{1}{\pi}pv \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \ast f$, where $f$ is in Schwartz space.

By definition, $$\frac{1}{\pi}pv \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \ast f=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac 1\pi\int_{\mid y\mid\geq \epsilon} f(x-y)\frac{dy}y.$$ But it is the fact that the right hand side converges to $H(f)$ when we take the limit in the $L^2$ sense.

The book does not discuss this and I was wondering if we define the principal value in such a way ($L^2$ convergence). Thanks for your help!

Comment: In order to define the distribution $p.v.\frac 1x$ you need to specify how it integrates against test functions $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. The limit that pops up there is just in $\mathbb{R}$ and so you don't need to talk about $L^2$-convergence. On the other hand, you can define the Hilbert transform on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ without reference to the distribution $p.v.\frac 1x$ by saying that $Hf$ is the $L^2$-limit of $H_\epsilon f$, where the $\epsilon$-subscript denotes the obvious integral with $\epsilon$-interval cut out.

Comment: @Jan Bohr what's the difference between the right-hand side on the above equation and $H_\epsilon f$ as $\epsilon\to 0$? They have the same equation but the former takes values in the real number? But ultimately, I need to prove that they are equal in the distribution sense (from my understanding)

Comment: Thinking it over, my best guess is that the author actually meant that they are equal as $L^2$ functions